BertTokenizer has no attribute named save_pretrained
from transformers import BertTokenizer

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("fnlp/bart-base-chinese")
# some manipulations here, omitted
tokenizer.save_pretrained("my_tokenizer") # it works! 

Output is:
('my_tokenizer/tokenizer_config.json',
 'my_tokenizer/special_tokens_map.json',
 'my_tokenizer/vocab.txt',
 'my_tokenizer/added_tokens.json')

Then, I wrap the tokenizer to upload to HuggingFace:
from transformers import PreTrainedTokenizerFast

wrapped_tokenizer = PreTrainedTokenizerFast(
    tokenizer_object=tokenizer,
)

wrapped_tokenizer.push_to_hub('my-tokenizer-bert', private=True)

It fails with:

AttributeError: 'BertTokenizer' object has no attribute 'save'

The full stacktrace is:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 7
      1 from transformers import PreTrainedTokenizerFast
      3 wrapped_tokenizer = PreTrainedTokenizerFast(
      4     tokenizer_object=tokenizer,
      5 )
----> 7 wrapped_tokenizer.push_to_hub('my-tokenizer-bert', private=True)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py:781, in PushToHubMixin.push_to_hub(self, repo_id, use_temp_dir, commit_message, private, use_auth_token, max_shard_size, create_pr, **deprecated_kwargs)
    778 files_timestamps = self._get_files_timestamps(work_dir)
    780 # Save all files.
--> 781 self.save_pretrained(work_dir, max_shard_size=max_shard_size)
    783 return self._upload_modified_files(
    784     work_dir,
    785     repo_id,
   (...)
    789     create_pr=create_pr,
    790 )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py:2182, in PreTrainedTokenizerBase.save_pretrained(self, save_directory, legacy_format, filename_prefix, push_to_hub, **kwargs)
   2178 logger.info(f"Special tokens file saved in {special_tokens_map_file}")
   2180 file_names = (tokenizer_config_file, special_tokens_map_file)
-> 2182 save_files = self._save_pretrained(
   2183     save_directory=save_directory,
   2184     file_names=file_names,
   2185     legacy_format=legacy_format,
   2186     filename_prefix=filename_prefix,
   2187 )
   2189 if push_to_hub:
   2190     self._upload_modified_files(
   2191         save_directory,
   2192         repo_id,
   (...)
   2195         token=kwargs.get("use_auth_token"),
   2196     )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_fast.py:605, in PreTrainedTokenizerFast._save_pretrained(self, save_directory, file_names, legacy_format, filename_prefix)
    601 if save_fast:
    602     tokenizer_file = os.path.join(
    603         save_directory, (filename_prefix + "-" if filename_prefix else "") + TOKENIZER_FILE
    604     )
--> 605     self.backend_tokenizer.save(tokenizer_file)
    606     file_names = file_names + (tokenizer_file,)
    608 return file_names

AttributeError: 'BertTokenizer' object has no attribute 'save'

The result is contradicting. I double check my the class of the tokenizer object, it is:
print(type(tokenizer))
<class 'transformers.models.bert.tokenization_bert.BertTokenizer'>

Seems that BertTokenizer uses .save_pretrained() instead of .save(). How can I solve this issue to make the tokenizer successfully get wrapped by PreTrainedTokenizerFast and upload to HuggingFace?
Thanks.
p.s. Ultimately, I want to train this BertTokenizer with new dataset, but the BertTokenizer has no .train_from_iterator() either.

UPDATE If I swap PreTrainedTokenizerFast to BertTokenizerFast (which its subclass is also PreTrainedTokenizerFast), the error will become:

AttributeError: 'BertTokenizer' object has no attribute 'normalizer'

Isn't supposed the fast version can fully support the slow version?
